# Get most frequent value with SQL query

Tags: sql

I'm trying to write an SQL query where I find the value that occurs the most frequently.

So far, I have this:

```
SELECT GENRE, COUNT(*) AS Frequency 
FROM BooksRead 
GROUP BY GENRE
```

This gives me output like this:

```
Anthropological         1 
Biography               7 
Crime                   4 
Essay                   2
```

I want the returned result to be 7. I've tried using TOP 1 but my Java compiler doesn't seem to like it.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ANSI SQL syntax would be:

```
SELECT GENRE, COUNT(*) AS Frequency
FROM BooksRead
GROUP BY GENRE
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Not all databases support that syntax.  Many support `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT GENRE, COUNT(*) AS Frequency
FROM BooksRead
GROUP BY GENRE
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

However, the exact syntax depends on the database you are using.

You can also use ANSI standard window functions:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT GENRE, COUNT(*) AS Frequency,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM BooksRead
      GROUP BY GENRE
     ) g
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

If you want ties then use `RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`.